# How to replace repetitive pattern in a string in Java?

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, web-api-testing

I have intelliJ running with Java/REST API and having trouble removing and replacing string in a certain format.

Response string :

> {"isSuccess":[{"frequency":}]}]}}{"isSuccess":[{"frequency":}]}]}}{"isSuccess":<testData>[{"frequency":<testData>}]}]}}

Expected string :

> [{"frequency":}]},{"frequency":<testData>}]},{"frequency":<testData>}}]}]}}

Actual String :

> [{"frequency":<testData>}]}]}}[{"frequency":<testData>}]}]}}[{"frequency":"<testData>}]}]}}

Code :

```
public static String getResponseString(String response){
        String getIDErrorCodeString = response.split("\\[")[0];                 
        String getStringWithoutIDErrorCode = response.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(getIDErrorCodeString), "");
        String getStringwithBracket = "}]}]" + getStringWithoutIDErrorCode + "}}[{";

        String actualResults = getStringWithoutIDErrorCode.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(getStringwithBracket), ",");

        return actualResults;
}
```

The original string had the `}}[{` in the beginning of the line which got removed in the actual results but still pattern is not recognizing and finding the correct string to replace not just in the beginning but in the entire string. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Please update the question with the original input string.

Comment: @AndrewS updated

Comment: @Bubbles so you need to feed the Response string and remove the `}}[{` characters from it right ?

Comment: Yes but not all `}]}]}}[{` needs to be replaced. At the end we need to keep it. So how do I replace it only in the middle ?

Comment: It should look identical to expected results basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple than I wrote originally,

```
public static String getResponseString(String response){
        String getIDErrorCodeString = response.split("\\[")[0];                  
        
        String getStringWithoutIDErrorCode = response.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(getIDErrorCodeString), "");
        String actualResults = getStringWithoutIDErrorCode.replaceAll("]}}\\[", ",");

    return actualResults;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getResponseString(String response){

  String getIDErrorCodeString = response.split("\\[")[0];
  
  String getStringWithoutIDErrorCode = response.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(getIDErrorCodeString), "");

  String getStringwithBracket = "}]}]" + getStringWithoutIDErrorCode + "}}[{";

  String pattern = Pattern.quote(getStringwithBracket);
  String actualResults = getStringWithoutIDErrorCode.replaceAll(pattern, ",", Pattern.MULTILINE);

  return actualResults;

}
```

try using `Pattern.quote()` to escape the pattern string for regex and then
Add the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag so `^` and `$` match start/end of each line after this use the `g` flag in the regex to replace all occurrences
This will do a global regex replace to replace that pattern on each line.

-- Hope this helps

Comment: in replaceAll(pattern, ",", Pattern.MULTILINE); what does pattern refers to ?

Comment: `replaceAll(pattern,",",Pattern.MULTILINE)` there are 3 parameters in `replaceall()`method
1st param is pattern to match
2nd param is replacement string
3rd param sets optional regex flags

Comment: Its not working. Giving error `required type is String but provided int`

Comment: `replaceall()` method is giving this error ? or whole block ?

Comment: replaceAll() is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing all occurrences of `{"isSuccess":<testData>`.

```java
s = s.replace("{\"isSuccess\":<testData>", "");
```

Then, replace `]}}[`, with `,`.

```java
s = s.replace("]}}[", ",");
```

And finally, insert a `}`, at *n − 6*.

```java
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 6) + '}' + s.substring(s.length() - 6);
```

Output

```
[{"frequency":<testData>}]},{"frequency":<testData>}]},{"frequency":<testData>}}]}]}}
```